# Why is CORS Error Returned When Passing Encoded Data

Tags: c#, angular

I'm forced to work with poor data quality. One instance is that primary key value of a given table can contain spaces and special characters, e.g.  `35581/H0034-100003`

What I'm trying to do is get a record by it's primary key value, so the web API I setup is a GET:

```c#
[HttpGet]
[Route("Api/SaleHeaders/{saleNumberEncoded}")]
public SaleHdrViewModel GetSaleHeader(string saleNumberEncoded)
{
    var saleNumber = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(saleNumberEncoded);
    return _saleHeaderService.Get(saleNumber);
}
```

Then when I go to send the value from the front-end, I use:

```typescript
getSaleHeader(saleNumber: string): Observable<ISaleHeader> {
    saleNumber = encodeURIComponent(saleNumber);
    const url = `${environment.ApiUrl}/Api/SaleHeaders/${saleNumber}`;
    return this.http.get<ISaleHeader>(url);
}
```

The issue is that the request is failing, specifically due to a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:52864/Api/SaleHeaders/%2035581%2FH0033-100000' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I don't think that this is actually a CORS error. I think this actually has to do with CORS because if I edit and resend with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, it returns a 404. I think this has to do with trying to send encoded primary key value.

I know that I can change my request type from a GET to a POST and then just pass the primary key value in the body, but I'd prefer to keep getting records in a consistent manner (GET request with `Api/{table}/{pk}` route).

**Edit -** I've verified that if I pass an unencoded value (e.g. `00007931`) then the endpoint works fine.

Comment: I think you're missing the [`EnableCors`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Api/V1/ArtistController.cs#L27) attribute...

Comment: @Pieterjan -  Please see comments showing that it works if I pass an unencoded value.

Comment: If your encoded format contains `/` that would be a problem as it will be managed as another path

Comment: @JorgeMachado - the encoded format does not contain the slash. See the URL in the error message: `localhost:52864/Api/SaleHeaders/%2035581%2FH0033-100000` the slash is encoded as %2F

Comment: @David I am not sure about how an url like `localhost:52864/Api/SaleHeaders/%2035581%2FH0033-100000` could be readed... Honestly it seems weird...

Comment: @JorgeMachado - trust me, I know. That is why I lead off with "I'm forced to work with poor data quality." the database is 30 years old and allowed for user input for primary key values at one point.

Comment: @David if that is the only way you have... I could recommend you to write the characters in hex UTF-8 format or look for a base64 URL safe variant encoder... I am not sure about if that will solve the problem, but I think it would be a good try :)

Comment: please compare the sequence of calls that does work with the sequence of calls that does not work. It must be doing a preflight options calls to get do the "CORS" check... My suspicion is that the CORS preflight check is working with the unencoded value but it is not working with the encoded value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Jorge Machado's advice that was posted in the comment section of encoding the value to Base64 and then decoding it on the server.

Angular:

```typescript
getSaleHeader(saleNumber: string): Observable<ISaleHeader> {
    saleNumber = btoa(saleNumber);
    const url = `${environment.ApiUrl}/Api/SaleHeaders/${saleNumber}`;
    return this.http.get<ISaleHeader>(url);
}
```

C#:

```c#
[HttpGet]
[Route("Api/SaleHeaders/{saleNumberEncoded}")]
public SaleHdrViewModel GetSaleHeader(string saleNumberEncoded)
{
    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(saleNumberEncoded);
    var saleNumber = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    return _saleHeaderService.Get(saleNumber);
}
```

This allows me to keep with my existing pattern of having a GET endpoint where the route follows the following pattern: `Api/{table name}/{primary key value}`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use character `/` as a route parameter because it will be readed as a different resource access. I recommend you to use another pattern to encode your data and avoid missunderstanding the information. Otherwise you could pass the data as a query parameter using:

`http://testweb.z/route?userdata=123/321`

Also you can change your method signature to: (that's the way I recommend to you)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Api/SaleHeaders/{table}/{pk}")]
public SaleHdrViewModel GetSaleHeader(string table, string pk)
```